# In MongoDB, how can I find a document that is embedded?

Tags: mongodb, find, embed, document

I created an embedded document named "KPOP" in MongoDB, and I wanted to find the field with the value of "BTS: Fake Love"

Here is the embedded document:

```
> use TestMongoDB
  switched to db TestMongoDB
> db.KPOP.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd83447066c904c1365771a"),
    "KPOP" : {
            "SHINee" : "Dream Girl",
            "Girl's Generation" : "I Got a Boy",
            "BTS" : "Fake Love"
    }
}
```

Is something wrong with my code? After I press enter, nothing shows up.

```
> db.KPOP.find( {"KPOP": {"BTS": "Fake Love"}} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is something wrong with my code? After I press enter, nothing shows
> up.
>
> db.KPOP.find( {"KPOP": {"BTS": "Fake Love"}} )

That is the expected behavior.

If you want to query an embedded document's individual field(s) you need to use the following syntax - using the dot (`.`) notation. For example, both these queries return the document:

```
db.test.find({"KPOP.SHINee": "Dream Girl"})
db.test.find({"KPOP.SHINee": "Dream Girl", "KPOP.BTS": "Fake Love" })
```

In the above queries, you can specify one, two or all the fields *and* in any order.

You use the following syntax when specifying the filter for the *whole* embedded document:

```
db.test.find({ KPOP: { SHINee: "Dream Girl", "Girl's Generation": "I Got a Boy", BTS: "Fake Love" } })
```

In this case, note that the *order of the fields* of the embedded document must be same as that of the original document; i.e., `SHINee`, `"Girl's Generation"` and `BTS` (within the `KPOP`). And, you need to specify *all* the fields of the embedded document.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
db.KPOP.find( {"KPOP.BTS": "Fake Love"} )
```